# GoDaddy : htaccess location

Tags: .htaccess

Where is the default .htaccess file located in Godaddy linux server?

I have an api hosted on GoDaddy. I cannot send the ajax query due the CORS issues. I need to edit it's Access control origin settings.

If there's no .htaccess,where i should create one ?

Answer (score 0):

Create the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of the site you are working on or you can create it in subdirectories as well. The .htaccess in subdirectories will override the root. On Godaddy the root may be something like:

`/username/public_html/`

Wherever your homepage file resides, usually something like `index.html` or `index.php`.